# Transmit AJAX data after submit

Tags: ajax, jquery

I use the code below to submit my form without reloading the page, but when data.a="a", or "b", etc. in the success part of AJAX, I still would like to submit the form as conventionally done by php without jQuery.

So in this case, the aim is to transmit the AJAX data ("data:myForm.serialize()+"&id_town="+id_town,") to the url specified in the "action" html attribute of the form.

Do you have any idea ?

Html code:

```
<form id="inscription_form_home" action="index.php?module=membres&action=inscription" method="post" >
...
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("#inscription_form_home").submit(function() { 
var myForm = $(this);

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    url: "traitement_profil.php",
    data:myForm.serialize()+"&id_town="+id_town,
    success: function(data){
        if (data.a == "a" || data.a == "b" ){
            // Transmit the data part to the form url
        }else{                  
            alert("Inscription OK.");
        }
    }
});

return false;
});
```

Comment: are you asking how to make a second ajax call to the `action` url?

Comment: very poorly explained, cannot understand what you want

Comment: @charlietfl : Yes I think it could be the solution. How can we do that ?

Comment: need to be clear and concise on the redirect sequence you want. Forget the code..explain behavior start to finish in the body of question

Comment: Ok, I have just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As allready been said, you can do another ajax call inside the

Edition after comments, :

Try this...

```
<form id="inscription_form_home" action="index.php?module=membres&action=inscription" 

    method="post" >
    ...
    <button id="mButton">Submot<button>
    </form> 


$(document).ready(function() {$("#mButton").bind('click', mysubmit($));});

   function mysubmit()
   {    
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url: "traitement_profil.php",
        data:myForm.serialize()+"&id_town="+id_town,
        success: function(data){
            if (data.a == "a" || data.a == "b" ){
                //do your new call here, or you can also submit the form
            }else{                  
                alert("Inscription OK.");
            }
        }
    });    
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: I tried $("#inscription_form_home").submit(); instead of the comment inside the if loop, but it submits the form again and again. I think the solution isn't as simple.

Comment: yes, true, you added you ajax function to the submit function! hehe sorry didn't notice it. I suggest one workaround is: to create new function for the ajax call and bind it to the send buttond, and keep the submit inside the reply.

Comment: I understand but I'm not sure to be able to do this...Could you show me what the code looks like by editing your post please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this :

```
$(location).attr('href',YOUR URL);
```

Comment: My question is not about a simple redirection : I would like to transmit AJAX data in addition to the redirection.

Comment: Write another AJAX request in your scope like you made before. And after redirect. But it's better to make a big request than a lot of little requests.